# Youtube API nextPageToken becoming invalid

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to go through a Youtube playlist's items using the youtube data API, and I'm running into an issue in which the nextPageToken will be invalid seemingly at random. Here is my code:

[image]

After running the code, the program begins moving through pages. At some point in the program, it sometimes throws the invalid page token error, though. It does this inconsistently - sometimes it will make it through all the pages, sometimes it won't make it through the first, and sometimes it will mess up half way. This all happens in back-to-back runs in which I don't touch the code.
Here, a run went all the way through:

[image]

After it did, I just loaded up the program again:

[image]

Note: I'm not saving or loading anything between runs except OAuth credentials.

Comment: Please edit your question include your code and your error message directly. Dont post images.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with pagetokens https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35177262

Comment: This appears to be a bug, Google has acknowledged the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196413673).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same problem here, if you retry request few times it will eventually succeed

in nodejs api you can specify retry count and retry delay in request-options: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#request-options

edit: I don't know if it is correlated but google is experiencing some technical issues
[Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Cln.png)

https://status.cloud.google.com/